# How to send cookies in CreateView?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to implement signed cookie sending in CreateView, but I have encountered with the trouble. Following code works in UpdateView but in CreateView we dont  have self.object in  render_to_response method and basically we cant get  a pk there or at least  I dont know how to do it.

Question is how to get pk or id of a freshly created object or maybe alternatively in which method I could move my code to get access to pk from there?

Thanks.

```py
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):

    response = CreateView.render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs)
    existing_allowed_comments = self.request.get_signed_cookie('allowed_comments', default=None)
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        if existing_allowed_comments and str(self.object.pk) not in \
                existing_allowed_comments:
            response.set_signed_cookie('allowed_comments',
                 ", ".join([existing_allowed_comments, str(self.object.pk)])
        elif not existing_allowed_comments:
            response.set_signed_cookie('allowed_comments', self.object.pk
    return response
```

method should add pk of created objects to signed cookies in case user is not authenticated.

self.get_object() doesn't work as well – 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be better to override the `form_valid()` method for this. This method creates an object from the validated form data so you will have access to `self.object` after calling the method in the base class:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    response = super().form_valid(form)
    existing_allowed_comments = self.request.get_signed_cookie('allowed_comments', default=None)
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        if existing_allowed_comments and str(self.object.pk) not in \
                existing_allowed_comments:
            response.set_signed_cookie('allowed_comments',
                 ", ".join([existing_allowed_comments, str(self.object.pk)])
        elif not existing_allowed_comments:
            response.set_signed_cookie('allowed_comments', self.object.pk
    return response
```

Note that if the form is not valid because of bad data, no object will be created and this method will not get called.

Comment: thank you for the answer. You saved me few hours of my life